# How to create collection in collection in mongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I just started learning MongoDB. I want to create a collection in collection for example

```
College -> department -> (Students, teachers)
```

Is it possible or their is some another concept??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have got the wrong concept.

Collections in MongoDB are the equivalent to tables in Sql. So the quick answer is NO, you can't do that.

However, If in your design you have a collection that contains a list of something, you can have that list inside the collection.

Let's say you have a Person collection, which contains a list of addresses. You can do that. Actually, think of MongoDB collection as a list of JSON documents, because that's what it is. You could have a JSON document, with the Person information and one of the elements is the list of addresses:

```
{
  "name":"person1",
  "addresses":[
    {"street":"whatever"},
    {"street":"whatever"}
   ]
}
```